# Compulsory Primary Key for Sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there any configuration setting in `SQL Server 2008` for put `Primary key must` when create a New table ?

I know Oracle does not allow to create a Table without Primary key.But SQL Server 2008 does not having such a restriction.

Do you know any method to do so (most of the time I forget to create it and SQL Azure will give error for that)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use DDL Triggers for this, and you'd have to parse Sql to check if PK is being created. 
I don't think there's another option.

Example:

```
create trigger trgTable
on database
for create_table, alter_table
as
set nocount on

declare @data xml, @obj varchar(255), @type varchar(255), @cmd varchar(max)
set @data = EVENTDATA()

select 
    @obj    = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(256)'), 
    @type   = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectType)[1]', 'varchar(25)'), 
    @cmd    = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'varchar(max)')

-- now do your logic here
```

Comment: Do you having such a sample trigger just for look ?

Comment: Could you tell me what would you mean by "now do your logic here" ?If I run above trigger on by DB will it require primary key when I create a new table ?

Comment: Now, it won't. But every time a table is being created, you have object name and sql to your disposal, so you can check if there's primary key or not. And you can make notifications, raise an error, drop the table...

Comment: Why don't you complete that logic also.B'cos I am not SQL master.We are doing Entity frame work code first.So no usage of SP or Trigger.If you don't mind could you give me a complete trigger which I can run and test the final Out come.Thanks in advance.