# Primary Key on SQL table

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

I have a SQL table, it contains about 6 columns and has 500,000 rows. It does not have a primary key though, there is no logical combination to create a primary key.

Should I create an extra ID column to be a primary? Would it help improve data retrieval? I am not going to query using the ID column.

Answer (score 0):

Primary keys are a type of index which has more constraints than a regular index (like being unique). Data retrieval efficiency depends on the chosen index - this is because the internal storage representation of your database is organised around it. Choosing a suitable index is dependent on what your actual queries are.

Whether a primary key is required would depend on your database management system. Judging by this question, it is not in MS SQL Server: [Compulsory Primary Key for Sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681150/compulsory-primary-key-for-sql-server)

As a very simple example, column 'a' may be a good candidate if most of your queries look like this:

```sql
select a, b, c
from table
where a > 123
```

[Use the index, Luke](https://use-the-index-luke.com/) is a great comprehensive resource on database indexing which could help you choose a suitable index based on your database's requirements.